# firewall or iptables script for linux to block all internet access except for desired applications?

Tags: linux, networking, firewall, iptables

linux firewall or iptables script to block all internet access except for desired applications ?

sth like an applications firewall which could block all network traffic passed on all applications except some i would select through a checkbox list.

For example on a Linux machine i would like to use just web browser, mail client and software updater with access on the internet, and everything else should be blocked.

Thank you

Comment: IMHO looking at the firewall is the wrong place. Better done with something like apparmor.

Comment: it is just for sillyphones, and i really do not like that they give specific builds per client... they do not have one app for all